# php parse the string obtained inside the XML tag

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Recently i had to do an api call which returned an XML response. But it seems  like a strange XML with only 1 base tag and all other info is given as string inside this base tag. I need to get the value of each of these string tags, But don't know how to achieve this.

Below given is the sample response am receiving from the api.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://webservices/api/v1/Inventory.asmx">
&lt;NewDataSet&gt;
    &lt;Table&gt;
        &lt;ITEMNO&gt;120&lt;/ITEMNO&gt;
        &lt;IDESC&gt;BERG 22423 BULL .224 90GR VLD TGT  100&lt;/IDESC&gt;
        &lt;IMFSEQ&gt;570&lt;/IMFSEQ&gt;
        &lt;IMFGNO&gt;628&lt;/IMFGNO&gt;
        &lt;CSEQ&gt;0&lt;/CSEQ&gt;
        &lt;ITYPE&gt;7&lt;/ITYPE&gt;
        &lt;SHDESC&gt;Berger Bullets 22423 Target 22 Caliber .224 90 GR Target Very Low Drag 100 Box                                                                                                                          &lt;/SHDESC&gt;
        &lt;UOM&gt;EA&lt;/UOM&gt;
        &lt;PRC1&gt;34.73&lt;/PRC1&gt;
        &lt;CPRC&gt;34.04&lt;/CPRC&gt;
        &lt;QTYOH&gt;26&lt;/QTYOH&gt;
        &lt;WTPBX&gt;1.400&lt;/WTPBX&gt;
        &lt;ITUPC&gt;679459224239   &lt;/ITUPC&gt;
        &lt;MFGINO&gt;22423       &lt;/MFGINO&gt;
        &lt;SCNAM1&gt;BERG   &lt;/SCNAM1&gt;
        &lt;SCNAM2&gt;B22CAL &lt;/SCNAM2&gt;
        &lt;CATCD xml:space="preserve"&gt; &lt;/CATCD&gt;
        &lt;MFPRTYP xml:space="preserve"&gt; &lt;/MFPRTYP&gt;
        &lt;MFPRC&gt;0.00&lt;/MFPRC&gt;
        &lt;CATID&gt;36&lt;/CATID&gt;
        &lt;TXTREF&gt;120&lt;/TXTREF&gt;
        &lt;PICREF&gt;120&lt;/PICREF&gt;
        &lt;ITBRDNO&gt;628&lt;/ITBRDNO&gt;
        &lt;SERIES&gt;Match Grade                                                                                                                                                                                             &lt;/SERIES&gt;
        &lt;LENGTH&gt;4.1&lt;/LENGTH&gt;
        &lt;HEIGHT&gt;1.2&lt;/HEIGHT&gt;
        &lt;WIDTH&gt;3.3&lt;/WIDTH&gt;
        &lt;HAZAIR xml:space="preserve"&gt; &lt;/HAZAIR&gt;
        &lt;HAZGRND xml:space="preserve"&gt; &lt;/HAZGRND&gt;
        &lt;CHGDTE&gt;2018-05-23T00:00:00+00:00&lt;/CHGDTE&gt;
        &lt;LOADDT&gt;2015-11-05T00:00:00+00:00&lt;/LOADDT&gt;
    &lt;/Table&gt;
&lt;/NewDataSet&gt;
</string>
```

I tried the below methods but it does not seems to work as needed

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_string($myXMLData);
print_r($xml);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($myXMLData);
print_r($xml);
?>
```

what am looking is to get the value of each of the tags inside the response. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an XML document as text inside another XML document. So you have to load the outer document, fetch the text content and parse it as XML again:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://webservices/api/v1/Inventory.asmx">
&lt;NewDataSet&gt;
    &lt;Table&gt;
        &lt;ITEMNO&gt;120&lt;/ITEMNO&gt;
        &lt;IDESC&gt;BERG 22423 BULL .224 90GR VLD TGT  100&lt;/IDESC&gt;
    &lt;/Table&gt;
&lt;/NewDataSet&gt;
</string>
XML;

$stringElement = new SimpleXMLELement($xml);
echo $stringElement, "\n";

// force to string and parse as XML
$newDataSet = new SimpleXMLElement((string)$stringElement);
echo $newDataSet->Table->ITEMNO;
```

Output:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <ITEMNO>120</ITEMNO> 
    <IDESC>BERG 22423 BULL .224 90GR VLD TGT 100</IDESC>
  </Table> 
</NewDataSet> 

120
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) to transform your string into proper XML:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(html_entity_decode($myXMLData));
print_r($xml);
```

Demo here: https://3v4l.org/AWWEH

Comment: That did worked really well, thankyou very much...
@Nick hehehe nice ....

Comment: Actually it is semantically wrong and can break valid XML. You're removing escaping from the whole XML document. It only works because here is no escaped character except inside the text node.

Comment: @ThW Well, if there were any escaped character inside text nodes, they would need to be double encoded (in the input string) anyway. How else would you have a "<" within a text node, otherwise?

Comment: @ThW Oh, you meant within the outer XML. Tbh I didn't even notice there was a "normal" (non-encoded) XML root around it. Your solution is more reliable in this case, upvoting it.

Comment: Yeah, it is quite a strange format. It even has a namespace that sounds specific for the inner XML. :-)